# How to have multiple fields (D/M/Y) for single date property in Yii?

Tags: php, model, crud, yii

I want to take user birth day into my database and there is a field in the table called **dob**. When I created model and CRUD it generated text field for **dob** as always. But I want to create three inputs.

1. For years
2. For Months
3. and for dates

**So my question is how to add extra inputs in the model's form. I was thinking of adding new attributes to the model class but there are no such attributes in the table.**

Comment: Try to add custom attributes to your model like $birthYear, $birthMonth, $birthDate. In your view add this attribute names to your inputs. And in the model you can write your beforeValidate or beforeSave function which will has something like $this->fullDateColumn = $this->birthYear.$this->birthMonth.$this->birthDay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the fields to your model:

```
public $year;
public $month;
public $date;
```

Add these methods to your model:

```
protected function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind();

    $dob = explode('/', $this->dob);
    $this->year = $dob[0];
    $this->month = $dob[1];
    $this->date = $dob[2];

    return $this;
}

protected function beforeSave() {
    parent::beforeSave();

    $this->dob = $this->year .'/'. $this->month .'/'. $this->date;

    return $this;
}
```

You can now use them in your CActiveForm form:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'year'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'month'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'date'); ?>
```

Comment: Do i need to add those new fields in attributeLabels method?