# Custom fields are null on form submit in Yii

Tags: php, forms, model, yii, cactiverecord

I added three new fields to my model (year, month, date). When I submit the form data isn't get populated. All those three custom attributes are null on submission.

[I have asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328125/how-to-have-multiple-fields-d-m-y-for-single-date-property-in-yii) on implementing multiple fields for single property and I did what the answer suggested. What should I do. Here is my code.

**User model:**

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $month;
    public $year;
    public $day;
    ...
```

**View file:**

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, "dob"); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'year', $model->getDobOptions('year')); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'month', $model->getDobOptions('month')); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'day', $model->getDobOptions('day')); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember to set those fields as safe as well?

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('month, year, day', 'safe'),
    ...
```

If you do not, this does not 'copy' the values over from the form to the model in the controller:

```
$model->attributes = $_GET['User'];
```